# Code Completion in PGAdmin dialogs

Tags: pgadmin

I just installed Postgres 9.5 and PGAdmin under Xubuntu 16.04.

When creating a new table column, something has changed when selecting datatype:

New Object -> New Table -> Columns -> Add -> Datatype

You cant type anything in. Choosing datatype has to be done either by scrolling down with mouse or using keyboard cursor. It is not possible anymore to type just "c" and it completes to "character" and so on.

PostGres 9.5 didn't behave like this under windows but maybe it is normal under Linux?

Answer (score 4):

PgAdmin's autocompletion is not automatic, but needs to be triggered (in each case) by pressing a key combination (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> by default). Refer to the documentation in https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/query_tool.html (for PgAdmin4, or [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20161112211934/https://www.pgadmin.org/gitrepo/pgadmin3-dev/docs/en_US/_build/html/query.html) for PgAdmin3).

Comment: See my edit. It happens at "New Column..." -> Properties Tab -> Data Type. Datatype cant be typed in, only selected.

Comment: Is there no way to change the default keyboard shortcut ?

Comment: @MCMZL in PgAdmin4, "alternate shortcuts can be configured through File > Preferences if desired", see https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/keyboard_shortcuts.html

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find it under File> Preferences > Query Tools > Keyboard shortcuts. I am running version 6.14